# Attempt to invoke android.os.Looper on null object reference with GoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android-studio, nullreferenceexception, android-looper

I am trying to convert my application into a Service, so that it cannot be destroyed as easily and stays running. I've moved code around several times trying to figure out the correct places for it for ease of use, but now I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.Looper com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.getLooper()' on a null object reference

It happens within this code block:

```
public void initiateMockLocs() {
    Location mockLoc = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    mockLoc.setLatitude(41.881832);
    mockLoc.setLongitude(-87.623177);
    mockLoc.setAccuracy(20);
    mockLoc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mockLoc.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime());

    try {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockMode(mMainActivity.mGoogleApiClient, true);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockLocation(mMainActivity.mGoogleApiClient, mockLoc);

        Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mMainActivity.mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i("Mock Location: ", loc.toString());

        Log.i("Timer", "Going to start timer.");
        logLocation();
        startTimer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Specifically, at the first line under the "try" block. The function is the only thing called in my onCreate of this Service, so it's called there. Some other background info where mGoogleApiClient is initialized is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    createLocationRequest();
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    showProcesses = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listApps);
    showProcesses.setOnClickListener(listRunningApps);

    activateMockLocs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activateMock);
    activateMockLocs.setOnClickListener(activateMockLocations);

    latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latView);
    longView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longView);

    anonymizationService = new AnonymizationService();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
// Initialize a LocationRequest object
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
}
```

If anyone knows the proper way to let the MainActivity talk with the Service and fix this problem, that would be great! I cannot seem to find an answer that deals with my exact problem. Thank you in advance.